# Programmatically handling missing/incorrect routes

Tags: routes, angular

Lets assume we have three routes:

- /
- /login
- /reports

Currently an error is thrown to console if user manually enters non-existing route, like /bla-bla:

```
browser_adapter.js?d744:76 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError
at resolvePromise (angular2-polyfills.js:543)
at angular2-polyfills.js:579
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:365)
at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js?ae31:35)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:364)
at Zone.runTask (angular2-polyfills.js:263)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (angular2-polyfills.js:482)
at ZoneTask.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:434)
```

URL then remains invalid: /bla-bla.

I would like to know is it possible to install route error handler to be able to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a definition with path `/**`:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/',name:'Home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'/reports',name:'Reports',component:ReportsComponent},
  {path:'/login',name:'Login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'/**',component:InvalidRouteComponent}
])
```

The path: `/**` will match every path that is not defined already.

In InvalidRouteComponent, you can inject `Router` to access the lastNavigationAttempt:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'default-route',
    template: 'This is an invalid path: {{lastRoute}}'
})
export class DefaultComponent {
  lastRoute:string;
  constructor(private _router:Router){
    this.lastRoute = _router.root.lastNavigationAttempt;
  }
}
```